If $A$ is a matrix such $( A-2I ) ( A-4I ) = 0$, why can't I assume $A = 2I$ or $4I$?

If $A$ is a matrix such $( A-2I ) ( A-4I ) = 0$, why can't I assume $A = 2I$ or $4I$?

$I=$ Identity matrix
$0=$ null matrix
My hypothesis-
$(A-2I)(A-4I) =0$
So either $A-2I =0$ or $A-4I =0$
So, $A=2I$ or $4I$

Welcome to MSE. Please include what you want to know in the body of the question, not just the title.

I did it for you, and also removed "non singular", because it was redundant: if $A^2-6A+8I=0$, i.e. $I=\frac18(6I-A)A$, then $A$ is invertible.

Does this answer your question? If $A$ is not invertible, then there exists $B$ such that $AB=0$

Matrices are not an integral domain, i.e. the product of two non-zero matrices can be null. For instance with
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix} \quad B = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
you have $BA=0$ while neither $A$ nor $B$ is null.

The question was originally asked for addition not multiplication. Can you elaborate with addidtion?

What do you mean by addition ?

Have a look at what happens for $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The real matrices ring has zero divisors when $n \ge 2$. Here, $A-2 I$ and $A -4I$ are singular matrices despite $A$ being non-singular.

Thanks for the answer . But is 2 I and 4 I a valid answer for the question?

$2I$ and $4I$ are indeed solutions of the equation $(x-2I)(x-4I)=0$. But those are not the only ones. The $A$ of my answer is another solution.
